# Can I use "trimming" in the meaning of "add or remove extra materials and obtain the final format"?

Tags: word-choice

We are writing a journal article with some friends. I want to tell them that we have to finish the main part of the work by mid-May, then we have time to "add or remove extra materials and obtain the final format". Can I use the word "trimming" in this context?

> Let's finish the main part by mid-May, then we have time for trimming.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Good. I'll accept your comment as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Trimming* (i.e., removal of excess or extraneous matter) cannot include adding material. A better term would be *editing*, *revision*, *polishing*, or *modification*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure whether you can trim (= edit) an article/a text.
Apart from using specific tools having a trimming function.

Comment: If an article is too long, an editor or publisher might say 'trim 150 words from your piece' to a writer.